# argc/argv problems in c

Tags: argv, argc

i'm extremely rusty with C and when trying to compile this i keep getting the error: "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" in each of the three nested ifs.
i'm pretty sure i'm doing some really dumb and basic mistake but i can't manage to fix it!

also the code is extremely naive, is there a better way to check the various strings in argv (they must be 6 charachters long, the first 2 charachters must be either IC, FR or RG and then the other 4 should be a numeric code) and print the correct strings?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int i=1;

while(i < argc){
if(strlen(argv[i]) == 6){

if(argv[i][0] == 'I' && argv[i][1] = 'C' && argv[i][2] >= '0' && argv[i][2] <= '9' && argv[i][3] >= '0' && argv[i][3] <= '9' && argv[i][4] >= '0' && argv[i][4] <= '9' && argv[i][5] >= '0' && argv[i][5] <= '9'){
    printf("%s", argv[i]);
}

if(argv[i][0] == 'F' && argv[i][1] = 'R' && argv[i][2] >= 0 && argv[i][2]     <= 9 && argv[i][3] >= 0 && argv[i][3] <= 9 && argv[i][4] >= 0 && argv[i][4] <= 9 && argv[i][5] >= 0 && argv[i][5] <= 9){
    printf("%s", argv[i]);
}

if(argv[i][0] == 'R' && argv[i][1] = 'G' && argv[i][2] >= 0 && argv[i][2] <= 9 && argv[i][3] >= 0 && argv[i][3] <= 9 && argv[i][4] >= 0 && argv[i][4] <= 9 && argv[i][5] >= 0 && argv[i][5] <= 9){
    printf("%s", argv[i]);
}
}
i++;
}


return(0);
}
```

EDIT: Damn this was a pretty dumb question, wrote = instead of == in the second assignment. thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you think `argv[i][1] = 'C'` does in an `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a typo in your second tests in each if, having written = (assignment of a value) instead of == (test for equality).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct but not intuitive. The compiler interprets your​ code as follows (note the extra parentheses I inserted):

```
if ((arg[0] == 'C' && arg[1]) = 'I') {}
```

This is because && binds more tightly than =. Replace the = with ==, and you're fine.

You should write a helper function:

```
static bool parse_number(const char *arg, char ch1, char ch2, int *pnum) {
    if (arg[0] == ch1 && arg[1] == ch2 && '0' <= arg[2] && arg[2] <= '9') {
        char *end;
        unsigned long num = strtoul(arg + 2, &end, 10);
        if (*end == '\0' && end - arg == 6) {
            *pnum = (int)num;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
int num;
if (parse_number(argv[i], 'I', 'C', &num)) {
    printf("IC number %d\n", num);
}
```